# Swift InputStream.hasBytesAvailable() returns false when reading a file on the desktop in swift how do I fix this?

Tags: swift, macos, inputstream, file-permissions, appstore-sandbox

I'm creating a Swift finder sync extension that needs to read the file data into an array to send to an api but it won't read it into the array because `InputStream.hasBytesAvailable()` returns false so won't enter the for loop. my app requires the app sandbox which iv'e got "User Selected Files" and "Downloads" folder given read/ write access. I've also given the app full disk access in my system settings.

This is my block of code causing the error specifically at the start of the While loop.

```
  let filePath = "/Users/<user>/Desktop/film.mp4"

  guard let inputStream = InputStream(fileAtPath: filePath) else {
            print("Failed to create input stream")
            return
        }
        // This dictates how many bytes are in each packet it must be a multiple of 327,680
        let packetSize = 3276800
        inputStream.open()
        
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: packetSize)

        // Write data to bytesArray
        while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable{
            let bytesRead = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            
            if bytesRead < 0 {
                print("Failed to read from input stream: \(inputStream.streamError?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
                break
            } else if bytesRead == 0 {
                print("End of input stream reached")
                break
            } else {
                // Process the bytes that were read
                let data = Data(bytes: buffer, count: bytesRead)
                
                bytesArray.append(data)
            }
        }
        
        inputStream.close()
```

these errors are printed in the console when i hit the button:

- open flag(s) 0x01000000 are reserved for VFS use and do not affect behaviour when passed to sqlite3_open_v2
- cannot open file at line 46922 of [554764a6e7]
- os_unix.c:46922: (0) open(/private/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - Undefined error: 0

I have tried deleting the the app sandbox which can stop access to some files but when my app builds it doesn't run properly and my option doesn't appear in the context menu and no setup logs are printed to the console.

It works in my first app that doesn't have an app sandbox and isn't split over two targets.

Any help is much appreciated

***** Update *****

I think I may need to add `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-only` to my .extensions file to let my app be able to access my home folder. It is a finder sync extension so needs to be sandboxed and this looks like the way to get around it.

[image: Picture of my .entitlements file in xcode]

Does anyone know if this is correct?

Thanks